# Unable to add Imageview reference in dictionary to view

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, but essentially I want to instantiate my uiimageviews when the controller loads. Afterwards, when I implement a method that executes on a timer, I want to grab the reference of the uiimageview depending on the index and add it to the view.

I'm using a NSMutableDictionary. I have all the code in the same method just to test it out. Shouldn't [self.view addSubview:poster]; place the first image in the current view?

```
self.images = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 280.0);


UIImageView *image_one = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
image_one.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_one.png"];
NSString *theKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",0];
[self.images setObject:image_one forKey:theKey];





UIImageView *image_two = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
image_two.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_two.png"];
NSString *theKey1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",1];
[self.images setObject:image_two forKey:theKey1];



UIImageView *poster = (UIImageView *)[self.images objectForKey:0];
[self.view addSubview:poster];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would suggest using an NSMutableArray. Since you are referencing the items in the array by an index anyways, might as well use an array.

Although with this code, there are a couple things you should change. You should allocate the NSMutableArray instead of using the autoreleased version.

When you are accessing the UIImageView, the key is a string, not an integer. So, it should read:

```
UIImageView *poster = (UIImageView *)[self.images objectForKey:@"0"];
```